# Selenium package for automating browser interactions

Tags: python, selenium

I am using selenium to automate repetitive task. It works really well. But I ran into a issue where I get an email sent to me which has a download button in it. I am not sure how to click on it? I can get the xpath but that only works once. Any help would be great!

Here is the button I am trying to select
[Email's button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR2oq.png)

```py
download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="m_-2340741114430056650background-table"]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody')
```

The xpath only works once after I grab that specific path. The idea is that this email is sent every week and for me to automatically select the button for the download. There isn't other identifiers like name or id, etc for this element. The email is sent from another company, so I don't think I have access to changing the way it is sent.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Its unclear if you create that email yourself. If so post your code.

Comment: your tried code ? HTML code ?